# Как такое возможно? Одинаковые строки не равны

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Смотрю на цикл значит я, не понимаю, почему он не работает, ведь я уверен в правильности работы, ладно, надо по шагам разгрести это безобразие, начал смотреть, а тут такое...
[image: Нечто]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
        view = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ShopItem, null, false);
    ImageView iv = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
    TextView tv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
    tv.Text = list[position].Name;
    // string img_name = "";
    // iv.set
    // Drawable d;
    var imgId = 0;
    foreach(var it in typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetFields())
    {
        var s1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(it.Name);
        var s2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(list[position].GetImgSource());

        if (it.Name == list[position].GetImgSource())
        {
            imgId = (int)it.GetValue(null);break;
        }
    }
    // iv.SetImageDrawable(Resource.Drawable.)
    // iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Переведите в byte array и выведите обе на экран.Джон Скит [говорит](https://habr.com/en/post/165597/), что проблемы со строками бывают весьма неожиданные. PS Боже, какой мелкий скриншот, вы не могли бы уважительнее отнестить к участникам и сделать скриншот не таким широким, чтобы браузер дополнительно не уменьшал ваш и без того мелкий шрифт?

Comment: Покажите хоть какой-нибудь связанный с этим код, а то здесь сейчас можно нагадать какие угодно вещи (например, изменившийся position)

Comment: Ну, это строки разной длины: одна 4 байта, другая 5. Ищите скрытые символы. Только я вообще имел ввиду показать каждый байт, а не просто длину.

Comment: Добавил код и количество байтов действительно   не равно, как это понять?

Comment: Раскройте массивы (треугольничек слева). Вы же видите, что они разной длины.

Comment: это название "ut_10" генерируется автоматически еще до входа в этот метод, могут ли из за этого добавиться скрытые символы?

Comment: лишний символ там это "?" но почему его не видно?

Comment: Может все, что угодно. Мы же не видим код, который скрывается за словом "генерируется".

Comment: Ну что, достаточно разобрались, можно закрывать как не воспроизводится или вызван опечаткой? )

Comment: @AK Ты полагаешься на Джона Скита? :)

Comment: @FikiFree: это не символ `?`, просто редактор, в котором Вы пытались его просмотреть, использует шрифт, в котором не существует графического отображения для «скрытого» символа. Разбирайтесь в функции генерации, где она Вам лишний символ приписывает

Comment: Видимо, это [был](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/935827/213987) связанный вопрос.

Comment: Ну да, так оно и есть, вообще много чего я уже проверил, и пришел к тому, что это из за DownloadFile